# script to look for a string and replace it with random chars and numbers

Tags: random, vim, replace

Is it possible to write a script for vim so that it looks for a string for example, gkfjjcjfk8483jdjd7. And then replaces the found string with another randomly generated string? It must be able to generate random string of numbers and other characters.

If anyone can help me with such a script I would truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
function! ReplaceWithRandom(search)
    " List containing the characters to use in the random string:
    let characters = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',]

    " Generate the random string
    let replaceString = ""
    for i in range(1, len(a:search))
        let index = GetRandomInteger() % len(characters)
        let replaceString = replaceString . characters[index]
    endfor

    " Do the substitution
    execute ":%s/" . a:search . "/" . replaceString . "/g"

endfunction

function! GetRandomInteger()
    if has('win32')
        return system("echo %RANDOM%")
    else
        return system("echo $RANDOM")
    endif
endfunction
```

The function can be called like this : `:call ReplaceWithRandom("stringtoreplace")`. And it will replace all the occurences of the string passed as argument by a random string composed of the characters listed in `characters`.

Note that I included an helper function which get random numbers from the system since Vim doesn't provides a random generator.

As a bonus you can make it a command to fasten the call:

```
command! -nargs=1 RWR call ReplaceWithRandom(<f-args>)
```

You can then do : `:RWR "stringtoreplace"`

---

**Edit**: And if you want the random string to be different on each of the occurences of the searched string you can replace the function by this one:

```
function! ReplaceWithRandom(search)
    " List containing the characters to use in the random string:
    let characters = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',]


    " Save the position and go to the top of the file
    let cursor_save = getpos('.')
    normal gg

    " Replace each occurence with a different string
    while search(a:search, "Wc") != 0
        " Generate the random string
        let replaceString = ""
        for i in range(1, len(a:search))
            let index = GetRandomInteger() % len(characters)
            let replaceString = replaceString . characters[index]
        endfor

        " Replace
        execute ":s/" . a:search . "/" . replaceString 
    endwhile

    "Go back to the initial position
    call setpos('.', cursor_save)

endfunction
```